# Does the width of a table parent element expand to its children?

Tags: html, css

`<table>` has a set width of 1000px.

It has 5 `<td>` elements each with a width of 300px.

Does table expand to contain all the `<td>` children despite me explicitly setting the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width you apply to the `table` is the most important.

The `td` elements will resize to fit inside the table

Comment: Thanks, can I just set the widths for my <td> columns, and the table width will contain them as if its width was auto?

Comment: yes, but you will have to **not** give a width to the `table`. (*you should look at `colgroup` and `col` tags : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.1*) also note that a table cannot exceed the width of its container (*if it is set*)

Answer (score 1):

This likely depends on the browser as well as how the widths are actually specified, but in your case most likely the table cells will be resized to fit the width of the entire table.  A description of calculating table width: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout

`table-layout: fixed` will use the fixed table layout algorithm which will calculate the table width from the normal box model using its contents (and be 1500px in your case).  You can also do this by having block level elements as the contents of the `<td>`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/AS6EZ/

Answer (score 0):

No. The table will not exceed a set width no matter the width of it's child columns. The table in your example will be 1000 px wide, not 1500 px wide.

Answer (score 0):

The child elements (the `td`'s) will resize to fit the width of the table.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/d96bL/).